# How to call "git pull" through rest api in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have been working on TFS for last couple days and I tried to implement "git pull" through rest api.

I followed Rest api Doc

```
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/overview
```

The documentation has "Create,Delete,View" functionalities.
I am not sure, how to pull the git repo using TFS rest api.

Please give me some suggestions or blogs to resolve this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: VSTS Rest API does not support "pull" action, you can use "libgit2" as Giulio mentioned.

Comment: I have used this URL- git clone https://$GH_TOKEN@github.com/owner/repo.git

Answer (score 1):

Invoke `git.exe` as a process or use client library like [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) or [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp).

TFS/VSTS implements standard Git HTTP protocol (see [Smart HTTP](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)) so there is no need for a special custom API for standard Git operations.